# Jquery click event not working on generated tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Example 1**

HTML

```
<a class="datafile" href="#">abc</a>
<div id="result2">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".datafile").click(function() {
$('#result2').append('ABC');   
});
```

**Example 2**

HTML

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="Click!"></input>
<div id="result2">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#button").click(function(){
$('#result2').append('<a class="datafile" href="#">abc</a>')
});
$(".datafile").click(function() {
$('#result2').append('ABC');   
});
```

In example 1 ,clicking on `abc` appends `ABC` in `div` tag whereas in example 2 ,clicking on button inserts `a` tag inside `div` but after that clicking on `abc` doesn't append `ABC` in `div` tag.

Why in example 2 `ABC` is not getting append?
How can I achieve this ?

[Example 2 on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4ur4v/X5gcj/3/)

**EDIT**

Using `on` works,but in this case how would I get attributes,val specific to the linked that was clicked ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code `$(".datafile").click(...)` attaches an event handler to existing elements only. To get events for new elements you either need to add new event handlers after adding the elements, or you need to add a single event handler to a common parent element, fex the body element. To do this use the selector argument of the jQuery `on()` function as follows:

```
$("body").on("click", ".datafile", function () { /* ... */ });
```

This will catch all events to current and future element with the class `datafile`̧.

The element that generated the event, ie the clicked element, can be accessed using `$(this)`. See http://api.jquery.com/on/ for details.

Comment: Hi... using `on` works,but in this case how would I get attributes,val specific to the linked that was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Try THis

```
 $("#button").click(function(){ 
 $('#result2').append('<a class="datafile" href="#">abc</a>')
  });  

 $("body").on('click','.datafile',function() {
 $('#result2').append('Loading Log File ...'); 
 // get value of href
 alert($(this).text());  
 });
```

You are creating element on fly so you need to use `.on` jquery function

Comment: Hi... using `on` works,but in this case how would I get attributes,val specific to the linked that was clicked.

Comment: use `$(this)` to get anything related like to get val of href you can do `$(this).text()` edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you are trying to achieve

```

```
$("#button").click(function(){
 $('#result2').append('<a class="datafile" href="#">abc</a>')
});
$("#result2").click(function() {
 $(this).append('Loading Log File ...');   
});
```

```

Bare in mind you can change the last .append to .html to replace the abc with loading log file...

Answer (score 0):

Found this to work:

```
$(document).on('click', ".datafile", function () {
    $('#result2').append('<p>Loading Log File ...</p>');
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/X5gcj/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

TAS gave a good explanation to why it does not work.
Alternatively to on(), you could also use the live() method:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
$('#result2').append('<a class="datafile" href="#">abc</a>')
});
$( ".datafile" ).live( "click", function() {
  $('#result2').append('Loading Log File ...'); });
```